# Can't force centered caption in figures with IFACCONF.cls

Tags: floats, captions, document-classes

I'm doing a paper in which I'm required to use the ifacconf.cls document class. I can't seem to force my figures to have a center caption.
I've tried:

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

or

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics...
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
```

Link to the ifacconf.cls : https://www.ifac-control.org/Members/juanp/drafts/ifacconf_latex.zip

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could always redefine caption, but are you sure that you should? The usual reason for a publisher to specify a class is to remove such style choice from the author and force a house style

Comment: Well this is for a school paper. The teacher also provided a .docx template in which the captions are centered. We asked him and he said he wants them to be centered, so that's the reason behind this post... It's stupid I know, but what can I do xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

the code has a comment saying it centres one line captions, but it doesnt..

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefigurecaption#1#2{\@figurecaptionsize
  \vskip \@overcaptionskip
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1. #2}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize              % IF longer than one line THEN
    \unhbox\@tempboxa\par                   %   set as justified paragraph
  \else                                     % ELSE
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\unhbox\@tempboxa\hfil}%   center single line. %make this comment true
  \fi}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{Zzz zzz zzz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```